# How to make navigate between pages faster in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm doing an application on windows phone

I use this method to navigate between pages

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

But if I navigate between 2 complex pages (e.g many images on these), the system delay quite a lot of time(2-3s) for navigating

I want to navigate to next page before loading data in second page, when navigating completed then just start loading data for this page
it should be like MARKET PLACE app in PHONE Device, it's so fast

Answer (score 0):

The page constructor and code in the Loaded event handler are executed before the first frame of the page is shown.

So if you want pages to be loaded fast, you should limit long-running operations like loading images in these methods.

One way that you can do this is to override `OnNavigatedTo` and start long-running operations in this method. `OnNavigatedTo` is called when a page becomes the active page.

Comment: I also already did like what you guide
 
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
            {
                return;
            }

            BindData();
        }
 
 But it's still slow, you can try by adding many images(about 40 images) on both pages
 You can see, performance is quite low, it's not fast like MARKETPLACE app

Comment: Do you really **need** to load 40 images directly? Maybe you could start by only loading the images that are on shown the screen (virtualization)

Comment: If i navigate from complex page(about 40 images) to new page, although new page is so simple(just 1 label) it's still slow